# How to set quotes for third layer of nesting in yaml for hass.io?

Tags: yaml, home-assistant

I have a simple TTS application that should respond with one of a few possible sentences after commanding the lights to turn *on* or *off* (trigger.event.data.state).

Unfortunately it currently reads literally "turning left curly bracket left curly bracket trigger dot event dot data dot state right curly bracket right curley bracket".

`payload: '{{ ["ok", "turning \"{{ trigger.event.data.state }}\" "] | random }}'`

I do need the outer ' ' quotes for home assistant. 
I also seem to need the " " quotes for the individual elements in the array.

How can I have a third level of quotes to get the trigger.event value in, so it reads "turning on" or "turning off" depending on the event?

I tried '' "" \" /", +, &, all sort of things to stitch that sentence together.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use a block scalar:

```
payload: >-
  '{{ ["ok", "turning \"{{ trigger.event.data.state }}\" "] | random }}'
```

`>` starts a *folded block scalar*.
All subsequent lines that are more indented are parsed literally without processing any special characters. Multiple lines are concatenated via a space character (unless separated with empty lines, which generate a newline character). The `-` modifier causes the final newline character of the last line to be stripped away (rather than being preserved, which is the default behavior).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Probably would work for YAML, but rhasspy does not interpret it correctly unfortunately. I tried replacing " with ' and vice versa, without the desired result.